# Flash On Chrome OS

Tags: javascript, html, flash, google-chrome-os

I have an Chrome app for Chrome OS that lets you run SWF files offline. The problem is when I use

```
<object data="flashFile.swf"></object>
```

It says that flash is blocked. I went to flash section in my settings and I see the apps that can and/or can't use flash but can't seem to be able to enable flash for my app. It also says it's enforced by an extension but I have no idea which one. Any suggestions?

(the picture below is a screenshot of the problem I am having)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple trick that will bring up an alert asking the user to allow flash on the website: `<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Enable Flash Player</a>`

This is guaranteed to work on Chrome, and works on Chrome OS but I'm not sure of other browsers or OSes, anyway, hope this helps. I myself have experienced the annoyances of the new default settings; they make it much harder to run flash!

Comment: I used <a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Enable Flash Player</a> but it didn't work. (I am working on a Chrome app)

Comment: Try to remove the target attribute, otherwise, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

After all this time I finally figured it out. In order to use flash in a chrome app you must copy the apps id, go to **settings --> content settings --> flash** and click the "add" button next to "allow" and then paste the apps id as the site.